# How namespace in android is used to resolve naming ambiguity?

Tags: java, android, xml

How could name space below used to resolve attributes naming ambiguity ?

```
 <parent xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <child></child>
   <child></child>
 </parent>
```

how distinguish between both child nodes?

since both **child** nodes inherit parent namespace.

then both must have the following name `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:child`

Comment: I dont understand. Both `LinearLayout` and `TextView` have android:height as attributes, and they are independents

Comment: @RafaelCardoso sorry i was mistaken, now question edited.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you define a namespace for the prefix `android`, so you are actually correct: the child nodes you'll end up using attributes in the format `android:attribute`.

However, it is possible to include some other namespaces. For instance,

```
<parent xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

  <child></child>
  <child></child>

</parent>
```

In this case, you have also defined the `app` namespace, which will include attributes defined specifically in your app (through libraries for example, or through custom views you defined). Thus, you would end up using both `android:attribute` syntax as well as `app:attribute` syntax for attributes that are not included in the `android` namespace.

The namespaces in android are not used to separate the child nodes themselves, but to define the scope of attributes these child nodes can access.